# Discord bot in Python reports "TypeError: Client.run() missing 1 required positional argument"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mak/PycharmProjects/pythonProject11/main.py", line 16, in \<module\>
client.run()
TypeError: Client.run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'token'
```

How can I fix this?

```
import discord
from discord.ui import button, view
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'My token was here'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Autenticazione riuscita. {0.user} is online!'.format(client))


client.run()
{TOKEN}
```

This code need to run/start the bot.

Comment: You need to pass the right arg to the method...how are you getting `{TOKEN}`? That isn't valid python so I'm not sure what you are doing with it, but have you tried passing the value of that like with a real variable name, something like this? `client.run(token=TOKEN)`

Answer (score 2):

put the token in the `client.run` method as an argument

```py
import discord
from discord.ui import button, view
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'My token was here'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Autenticazione riuscita. {0.user} is online!'.format(client))


client.run(TOKEN)
```